# uninitialized constant Api::Api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to namespace my controllers in my rails app. I have in my controller :

```
#controllers/api/auth_controller.rb
class Api::AuthController < ApplicationController
  def register
    
  end
end
```

And in my route file i have:

```
  namespace :api do
    get "auth/register", to: "api/auth#register"
  end
```

I keep on getting the error:

```
uninitialized constant Api::Api Object.const_get(camel_cased_word) ^^^^^^^^^^ raise MissingController.new(error.message, error.name) ^^^^^
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving you that error because you're telling rails to look for `api/` inside of `namspace :api` so it's trying to find `Api::Api`, You just need to remove the `api` from `api/auth#register`, it looks for api automatically since the route is under `namespace :api`, just do `get "auth/register", to: "auth#register"` and you should be good.

More on namespaces in routing [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Thanks a lot worked for me, I'm new to ruby and rubymine automatically imported the class for me